# Explicit solution SDE?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-differential-equations

I have the following SDE:
$$dY_{t}=A\left(\frac{W_{t}^{1}}{\sqrt{t}},\frac{Y_{t}}{\sqrt{t}}\right)dW_{t}^{1}+B\left(\frac{W_{t}^{1}}{\sqrt{t}},\frac{Y_{t}}{\sqrt{t}}\right)dW_{t}^{2}$$

where $W_{t}^{1}$ and $W_{t}^{1}$ are two independent brownian motions and
$$A(x,y)=a\frac{\Phi(y)\Phi(-y)e^{0.5(y^2-x^2)}+\Phi(x)\Phi(-x)e^{0.5(x^2-y^2)}}{1+a(1-2\Phi(x))(1-2\Phi(y))}, \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ B=\sqrt{1-A^2}$$

It seems unlikely, but I was wondering if there may be an explicit solution to this stochastic differential equation. Perhaps it can be reduced to a linear SDE with a suitable function?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is a monster but you may have help with the fact $$\Phi(-x) = 1 - \Phi(x)$$ and $$\sqrt{2\pi}\Phi'(x) = \mathrm{e}^{-0.5x^2}$$. Good luck with your work!

Comment: further to my comment $\left(dY_t\right)^2=dt$.

Comment: Yeah, Ive already used all of that in the derivation of A. Any comments relating the derivation of an actual explicit solution?

Comment: @Math Girl : The last comment of Chinny84 is very strong because if a solution exists it tells you that is has to be a Brownian motion tank's to Lévy's theorem on continuous local martingale, which is quite explicit in my opinion. Best regards

Comment: Yes it is and I was already aware of this. My question is whether there exists an explicit solution in terms of $W_{t}^{1}$ and $W_{t}^{2}$. Sorry, I should have made my question more clear.

Answer (score 0):

As observed in the comments, the quadratic variation of $Y_{t}$ is $t$

$$d\langle Y,Y \rangle_{t}=A^{2}dt+(1-A^{2})dt=dt\Rightarrow \langle Y,Y \rangle_{t}=t.$$

I am assuming $a>0$ is small enough to prevent a zero denominator. If so the coefficients are Lipschitz and so we have a strong solution. Since there is no drift, it is a continuous martingale [Why is a Itô integral w.r.t. Brownian motion a martingale?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2941183/why-is-a-it%c3%b4-integral-w-r-t-brownian-motion-a-martingale?noredirect=1&lq=1). Therefore, by [Levy's theorem](https://almostsuremath.com/2010/04/13/levys-characterization-of-brownian-motion/) it is a Brownian motion

$$Y_{t}=B_{t}.$$

From here if you really want, you can decompose into two independent Brownian motions

$$B_{t}=a W^{1}_{t}+\sqrt{1-a^{2}}W^{2}_{t},$$

for any $a\in [0,1]$. To recover the original $W^{i}$ doesn't seem possible because as you can see by taking expectation with one of them, we get nonlinear integral equations:

$$E[B_{t}|W^{2}]=\int^{t} E[A(W^{1}_{s}/\sqrt{s},B_{s}/\sqrt{s})|W^{2}]dW^{2}_{s}$$

and

$$E[B_{t}|W^{1}]=\int^{t} E[B(W^{1}_{s}/\sqrt{s},B_{s}/\sqrt{s})|W^{1}]dW^{1}_{s}.$$