# Why is this a martingale (SDE)?

Tags: stochastic-calculus, martingales, stochastic-differential-equations

I am reading a paper on the Fokker-Planck equation and this comes up. Let us consider the SDE in $\mathbb{R}^n$
\begin{equation}
dX_t = b(X_t,t)dt + \sqrt{2}dB_t, \qquad t\in [0,T],\\
X_0 = x_0
\end{equation}
where $B_t$ is a standard Brownian motion in $n$-dimension. My question is, if $\varphi:\mathbb{R}^n\times[0,T]\to \mathbb{R}$ is bounded and $\mathrm{C}^2$ in space, $\mathrm{C}^1$ in time, then
\begin{equation}
t\mapsto \int_0^t D\varphi(X_s,s)\cdot dB_s
\end{equation}
is a martingale? Here $D\varphi(x,s)$ is the gradient in $x$ of $\varphi$.

I am talking about page 35-36 in this note: [https://www.ceremade.dauphine.fr/~cardaliaguet/MFGcours2018.pdf](https://www.ceremade.dauphine.fr/%7Ecardaliaguet/MFGcours2018.pdf)

Comment: The gradient in $x$

Comment: Yes, as $X_s$ and $dB_s$ are independent, and $E(dB_s|F_s)=0$, this is almost always a martingale. Growth/convergence restrictions may apply.

Comment: @LutzLehmann I think some additional assumptions on the function $D\varphi$ are needed so that this function can be martingale. In other words, there may exist $\varphi$ that the function is not martingale (under the current assumptions).

Comment: Related https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2941183/why-is-a-itô-integral-w-r-t-brownian-motion-a-martingale/2943113

Comment: With the comment of @Joe, it suffices to construct the function $\varphi$ such that $$\int_0^t \left(D\varphi (X_s,s)\right)^2 ds < +\infty \quad \text{a.s}$$
$$\exists t_0>0: \quad E \left(\int_0^{t_0} \left(D\varphi (X_s,s)\right)^2 ds \right) = +\infty $$
Then the function $t\mapsto \int_0^t D\varphi(X_s,s)\cdot dB_s$ is a true local martingale (and not a martingale)

Comment: The lecture note I am reading claim that
$$ \mathbb{E}\left[\int_0^t D\varphi(X_s,s)\cdot dB_s\right] = 0$$
since $t\mapsto \int_0^t D\varphi(X_s,s)dB_s$ is a martingale. Is local martingale enough here to get the zero expectation?

Comment: The one I am reading is https://www.ceremade.dauphine.fr/~cardaliaguet/MFGcours2018.pdf

Comment: Local martingale is not enough. But I haven't known yet why this function is a martingale.